# electric turtlebot: android app can't load a map

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, map-saver, ros-electric, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone,

I'm working with Electric Turtlebot on ubuntu 11.10.

After downloading the latest mercurial source code of turtlebot_apps, the android "make a map" app works fine on my Android tablet.

But when i try to save the map, there's an error message on  the turtlebot netbook:

```
[ERROR] : Dynamic map getter service call failed.
```

It looks fine on the Android tablet though: "Map has been named xxxx."

Then I try to start the map navigation app, the tablet shows video stream, but can't load any map: "Starting the map selection service.."

After a few seconds, it just crushes.

Also the map manager app can't be started as well.

I've been looking at the topic data, it seems there's data published on /map when i try to save a map, but then the error messages appears, the SaveMap function stopped, and no data is published over /save_map.

Does anyone how to fix this problem??

Or is there anyway to get the source code of the android app? I might be able to have a look at the code and fix my problem.

Thanks....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28281/electric-turtlebot:-android-app-can%27t-load-a-map/) by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2012-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on 2012-05-15**:
Is anyone experiencing any luck regarding this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Update:

update the latest changes in turtlebot, and change the android_map_nav.launch file:
from:

to:

Now it works!

---

Originally posted by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) with karma: 32 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1